# How to make page mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, mobile

so I've got some problems with making a specific page on the website I'm making mobile friendly. I've got the mobile friendly meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` but that doesn't seem to do the trick. The problem is with the portfolio section under my test website at "www.websitetesting.pro"

The affected elements are the images under the portfolio, which are listed in rows of 3 in the "rowone" div, and the images themselves are under the figure element withing "rowone".
The problem is most likely withing the above stated elements within the CSS for the portfolio page, "portfolio.css".
Here's the code for that.

https://pastebin.com/wugN8SSy
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into responsive design a bit more. You have few problems, starting with `.column div` explicitly being set to 300px. You have 3 in a row, so if your screen resolution < 900px wide, this will obviously be a problem. It's a much better idea to set percentages.

You could start out by setting their width to 32% and the margin-left to 1% and setting a `max-width: 100%` on your `figure` elements inside of there to get a better idea of how to design responsive sites.

*Note:* These values are made arbitrarily for your example and wont equal exactly 100%. There are plenty of grids already made for responsive design. Although it's not my preferred solution, you may want to look into [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) as a jumping off point.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can go off of this. Sorry that this was probably a stupid question, I'm still trying to teach myself

Answer (score 0):

It is best to avoid setting fixed widths and using px for sizing. This is because different devices have different pixel counts and ratios. Try using em/rem for fonts and percentages for sizing the layout.

W3 Schools provides a good tutorial on RWD. Check it out.

[W3 Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Comment: Thank you for this, I will check it out.

Comment: Just to add to @BPierce's answer: This may be "best" in most scenarios but certainly not all. There are scenarios (like applications) that call for fixed width displays and pixel perfect layouts on mobile. This best practice is a good rule of thumb, but it shouldn't be causing the issue.